# Increase parent block height on expand of child block(absolute)

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have a situation where I need to expand invisible block on hover of parent block. parent is fixed width and child that expands is full screen width, therefore it is `position:absolute`. On expand element underneath is covered. I was trying to increase parent block height with jquery using parent height + expanding child height. However as this animating expand is done using max-height's jquery takes 0 as child's height.

Here is sample code and [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uqmctwh2/1/):
HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="list-el">
            <div class="el-top">Expand 1</div>
            <div class="el-bottom">Cupcake liquorice cupcake sweet roll ice cream caramels. 
                Lollipop dragée chupa chups. Sugar plum candy jelly-o bonbon gummies caramels.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-el">
            <div class="el-top">Expand 2</div>
            <div class="el-bottom">Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.list{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.list-el{
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background: #ff00ff;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.el-top{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
}

.el-bottom{
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
    transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f0fff0;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list-el:hover .el-bottom{
    max-height: 700px;
}
```

Maybe some ideas or suggestions how to increase parents height(using CSS or js/jquery) in the same animated manner?

Comment: Are you trying to make an accordion? Something like this [link](http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/Accordion-with-HTML-CSS-&-jQuery/)

Comment: Hi, nope, more like something similar to google images view, where you have a row of elements and when you click on one element row underneath slides down and this extra info appears, but row above stays. 
The end result when one of the blocks are expanded would look like this: [link](http://imgur.com/7k0Rc21)

Answer (score 1):

Well. I don't know if I have understood your questions well enough but... insteed of using javascript I would stick with just CSS.

Your problem may be that the `position:absolute´ of your hidden content doesn't fill (obviously) the height of the li as it's now out of the html flow.

Then as you can see in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/uqmctwh2/5/)**, I would make a work around and give the `position:absolute` to the li's insteed. then It's very easy to position these li's as their height is set (with respect of their parent ul that now needs `position:relative;`)

Now You just need to add:

```
.list-el:hover {
    height:auto;
    max-height: 700px;
}
```

Now as the hidden content is relatively positioned it will automatically "fill" the li.

Note: I have added `z-index:1`to your first li to be sure it's always on top, but if you change the li's html order in the html the result will be identical and you won't need the z-index (as the last element will be on top)

Comment: Can you add a link, because now fiddle link gives blank tab I guess you did not assign anything to it.

Comment: Done. I may have delete the link by mistakes on one of the editions.

Comment: This would be a good solution in other case, but now I am trying to achieve something like this: http://imgur.com/7k0Rc21

Comment: This is a possible solution of the question asked. What you try to achieve after this may be another question is you get a problem while trying to do it. Even if often I try my best to help others, I try to respect this web policy that we are not here to make other people projects, we are here to help when problems arise.

Comment: I do understand this. Thank you for help and answer. Maybe I should have added few more blocks to illustrate the situation better. Once again, thank you for your insights.

Comment: np. Good luck in your project

Answer (score 1):

According to the link you gave I assumed you wanted the expand 2 to move in order the leave enough space to the el-bottom class to expand.

Following this I used the flexbox css3 feature to automatically move the items following the expanding item.

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) is the doc I used.

Based on the code you gave and in order to make everything work you must :

- Add the "display: flex" property to the container class "list"
- Add the "flex-direction: column" property to the container class "list" to make items items "list-el" arrange vertically
- Add the "position: relative" property to "list-el" and "el-bottom" to tell the container to take their sizes into account. Otherwise, they will just overlap the next "list".

Here is my fiddle based on the code you gave :

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.list {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.list-el {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ff00ff;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
  position: relative;
}
.el-top {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
}
.el-bottom {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
  transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  background: #f0fff0;
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.list-el:hover .el-bottom {
  max-height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-el">
      <div class="el-top">Expand 1</div>
      <div class="el-bottom">Cupcake liquorice cupcake sweet roll ice cream caramels. Lollipop dragée chupa chups. Sugar plum candy jelly-o bonbon gummies caramels. Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow
        cookie. Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears. Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. Lollipop
        sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-el">
      <div class="el-top">Expand 2</div>
      <div class="el-bottom">Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears. Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. Lollipop sugar plum
        lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears. Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly
        lollipop pudding.
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```